# Map a function to part of sublist python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I am working in python and I have a list of lists (or could be also an numpy array) like this:

```
list = [[0, 0, -1], [1, 1, -2], [1, 2, -3], [2, 2, -4]]
```

I have a function that takes for every sublist the first two elements and gives a result. Let's assume that the function I am taking about is sum()
so what I want to do is

```
list1 = [[sum(0, 0), -1], [sum(1, 1), -2], [sum(1, 2), -3], [sum(2, 2), -4]]
```

and output is

```
list1 = [[0, -1], [2, -2], [3, -3], [4, -4]]
```

Is there a way to this with `map` or `numpy.vectorize`? I can already do it as a loop but it is too expensive for my real data.

Any help, advice?

Comment: For actual performance improvement, it would help to know about the implementation of the actual function in context.

Comment: or if you really want to use map, `map(lambda x: [sum(x[0:1]),x[2]], list)`

Comment: The function just takes the 2 coordinates, the first two values and performs a bitwise interleaving to create a sort of hash (morton code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) out of the coordinates. I think if it works for the sum I will be able to apply it to my actual function.

Answer (score 3):

In case of numpy array you should have the fastest results using vectorization:

```
In [128]: arr = np.asarray(list)
#Out[128]:
#array([[ 0,  0, -1],
#       [ 1,  1, -2],
#       [ 1,  2, -3],
#       [ 2,  2, -4]])

In [129]: np.vstack((arr[:,0]+arr[:,1], arr[:,2])).T
#Out[129]:
#array([[ 0, -1],
#       [ 2, -2],
#       [ 3, -3],
#       [ 4, -4]])
```

Comment: I am using the answer on the comments. For this specific one I need to use [numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to be able to apply a function to (arr[:,0], arr[:,1]) ? The sum was just an example. My function is more complicated.

Comment: you should add the function you want to use if you want vectorization!

Answer (score 2):

Could that be

```
[(sum(x, y), z) for x, y, z in list]
```

Or if you insist on using `map` use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
starmap( lambda x, y, z: (x+y, z), list)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, you could use a list comprehension as follows:

```
my_list = [[0, 0, -1], [1, 1, -2], [1, 2, -3], [2, 2, -4]]

answer = [[x + y, z] for x, y, z in my_list]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, -1], [2, -2], [3, -3], [4, -4]]
```

To apply a more complex generic function to each item in your list, use `map`:

```
def func(sublist):
    return [sum(sublist[:2]), sublist[-1]]

my_list = [[0, 0, -1], [1, 1, -2], [1, 2, -3], [2, 2, -4]]

answer = map(func, my_list)
```

By using the function `func` you can customise your function as desired.